# Search in all classes in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, search

I need to search a text in all classes in a eclipse project. For example write "test" in a class and I can't find it. How can I find it? Please help me.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to search a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to dialog from

Search->file